# WSO2 BAM Mediator - ESB Compatibility

Tags: wso2, compatibility, esb, wso2-bam, wso2-esb

Which [Carbon Repository](http://dist.wso2.org/p2/carbon/releases/) is intended to integrate / install  [BAM-Mediator](http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/BAM200/Managing+the+Feature+Repository) features into WSO2ESB 4.5.1 in combination with [WSO2BAM](http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/BAM200/Setting+up+BAM+Mediator) 2.0.1 ?

- 4.0.0
- 4.0.1
- 4.0.2
- 4.0.3
- 4.0.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Latest version compatible for `WSO2ESB 4.5.1` in combination with `WSO2BAM 2.0.1` is `4.0.3`. Use 4.0.3 version. It (4.0.3) has bugs fixed and implemented load balancing functionality with Thrift.

You can download p2 repository as a zip file from [here](http://dist.wso2.org/products/carbon/4.0.3/p2-repo.zip). Or can access the online p2 repository from the WSO2 Carbon home page.

Also note that your link refers to BAM 2.0.0 version. You can find documentation for BAM 2.0.1 [here](http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/BAM201/Setting+up+BAM+Mediator).

Comment: Thanks a lot, 4.0.3 works as supposed. We ran into some wired issue, that might be worth getting noted: If your BAM Box has several IP-Addresses assigned not all of them could get used for BAM-Mediators.

Comment: What do you mean by **BAM Box** ? Do you mean [BAM toolbox](http://maninda.blogspot.com/2012/10/bam-toolboxes.html) ? If then what is the name of the toolbox you mean? (e.g.: Activity Monitoring toolbox) Because WSO2 BAM has many available toolboxes.

Comment: The WSO2BAM server is installed on a host (Ubuntu 12.10) with several IP-Addresses assigned to that "BOX" aka Host. BAM-Mediators can not connect to that BAM-Server through all available IP-Addresses.

Comment: When load balancing, enter a string similar to {tcp://192.168.4.119:7611,tcp://192.168.4.120:7611} containing all the connection strings of BAM servers. It will load balance in the round robin manner. Note that this load balancing does not need the WSO2 Load Balancer or any other Load Balancer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [4.0.2](http://dist.wso2.org/p2/carbon/releases/4.0.2/plugins/) to install those features into ESB 4.5.1